# How to pass a text as command line argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

I'm trying to pass some text as a variable value by command line, but my problem is that my text contains spaces (and in some cases special characters) which seems to generate an error.

This is my MWE:

Test Cases:

```
Search in google
    Input query
    Submit query
```

Keywords:

```
Input query
    Input Text  xpath://*[@name="q"]    ${query}

Submit query
    Press Keys    xpath://*[@name="q"]      RETURN
```

Then, for some query, e.g.,

```
robot -d Results -v query:site:wikipedia.org Isaac Newton myrobot.robot
```

And the result

```
[ ERROR ] Parsing 'Isaac' failed: File or directory to execute does not exist.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely encasing in "double quote marks" (that kind) will work?

Are you inputting the command directly to terminal, or is it in for example a string that another program pushes to terminal - if so, check you have all the relevant quote marks.

`'robot -d Results -v query:site.wikipedia.org "Isaac Newton" myrobot.robot'`